# How can I use IF(AND() and IF(ISBLANK() in the same formula?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

What I want is:

If C3 is true and D3 is blank, nothing is put in K3.

If C3 is true and D3 is NOT blank, D3 is duplicated in K3.

i.e. My gamer username Nitrolysis, would be written in D3 and, if C3 was true, K3 would have my username in it too.

Sorry if this is confusing.

This code is in K3.

=IF(C3=TRUE)AND(IF(ISBLANK(D3),"",D3))

Please note that this is google docs sheets, not Office Excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
=if(and(C3=TRUE,D3<>""),D3,"")
```

Comment: Wow thank you so much!
Is there a way I could keep the username in the new cell when C3 becomes false? So it only works one way?

And then by changing D3's text and making C3 true again, it would overwrite K3 with the new name.